# equivalent metrics and uniform equivalent metrics

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let (X,d) be the Euclidean metric on the real number, and define σ(x,y)=min{1,d(x,y)} if 
if x, y are rationals or x, y are irrationals, and σ(x,y)=1 otherwise. I would like to study if these metric are equivalent, uniformly equivalent.
I think that they are not equivalent because if we think of any rational sequence converges to irrational. it would be convergent to 0 in d but to 1 in  σ. hence, those metrics are not equivalent and not uniformly equivalent. Is that correct?

Comment: the first metric is d(x,y)= |x − y| and the second metric is σ(x,y) which has two definitions: σ(x,y)=min{1,d(x,y)} if x, y are rationals or x, y are irrationals and σ(x,y)=1 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that’s correct. Since two metrics are equivalent if and only if they generate the same topology, you could also observe that $\Bbb Q$ is an open set in the $\sigma$-topology, since it’s the union of the open $\sigma$-balls of radius $1$ around its members, but of course it’s not an open set in the usual topology. Thus, the two metrics do not generate the same topology and cannot be equivalent (let alone uniformly equivalent).

If $\tau$ is the Euclidean topology, the topology generated by the metric $\sigma$ is the topology generated by $\tau\cup\{\Bbb Q,\Bbb R\setminus Q\}$ as a subbase. Equivalently, it has a base

$$\{U\cap\Bbb Q:U\in\tau\}\cup\{U\setminus\Bbb Q:U\in\tau\}\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. can you please explain how you choose this base 

$$\{U\cap\Bbb Q:U\in\tau\}\cup\{U\setminus\Bbb Q:U\in\tau\}\;.$$. Is that mean they are uniformly equivalent

Comment: @Memes: You’re welcome. The metric $\sigma$ is identical to the usual one on $\Bbb Q$ and also on $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, so each of those sets has the same relative topology with respect to $\sigma$ as it has in the usual topology. However, in $\sigma$ every point of $\Bbb Q$ is one unit away from every point of $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, so both sets are open. This shows that every set in my base is open in the $\sigma$ topology. Conversely, it’s not hard to show that every $\sigma$-open ball is a union of members of my base. Thus, my base generates the $\sigma$ topology.

Comment: Thanks I understand now. So Is that to enough now saying that they are not unifomrly equivalent (Lipchitz equivalent) because they are not equivalent?

Comment: @Memes: Yes: uniform equivalence implies equivalence, so if they’re not equivalent, they’re *definitely* not uniformly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.